German movie on Stalingrad war
As far as I can remember, it was a German movie before 2000. I only saw 15mins from the start and that is what I remember.
1) It was English translated version.
2) It was on Stalingrad war.
3) It was a color movie.
4) We see it from the point of view of a newly appointed captain/lieutenant/major.
5) The first scene is at some beach where they were bathing and playing cards. Later they are called to barracks where the army is promoted to the mentioned post. Next we see them sailing off for Russia in a freight train. They come to know about a Russian word in the train, "DAVAI". Next they are in war field where the captain kills one of his teammates as he could not see him clearly. Another scene I remember, the major protests against cruelty on Russian prisoners. That is it.

Could be Stalingrad (1993):

In August 1942, a group of German soldiers enjoy leave in Porto Cervo, Italy after fighting in North Africa. 
An awards ceremony is held for several soldiers in the unit, where one platoon's new commander, Leutnant (Lieutenant) Hans von Witzland is introduced. 
...

     

Watch the trailer 


Yes, this is the one! Thank you!
